# Is there a memory efficient way to concat variables in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that breaks over memory limit. I keep adding memory with `ini_set` but I'm reaching the physical limit.

So I'd rather fix the code than add more memory.

Here's then offending line which is in a loop:

```
$values_string .= $values . ',';
```

`$values` is always the same length of 77 chars (of course different ones).

So I read that PHP when doing `concat` actually creates a third variable. I wish to avoid that unnecessary temp variable creation.

Also, this is in a 40,000 iteration loop.  Is there a way to avoid the mess to accumulate (I mean in memory / garbage collector)?

Tried to increase memory limit with `ini_set` (worked for a time).

Comment: why would concat be your leak? Don't think this is ever the usual case, how much data are you appending? Surely just `explode()` or `implode()` would be suitable (based on your `.= $values. ',';`)

Comment: He is appending 40 000 strings of 77 chars long

Comment: What is the intended use of this huge string?  Is it going to be passed onto something, stored somewhere?

Comment: Agreed, what are you going to do with this enormous data? Perhaps you could write it out do its intended destination line by line instead of waiting till you collected it all?

Comment: Surely using a string with 3080000 chars doesn't really seem like a good idea..

Comment: It's prepare stuff to be inserted in a mysql database using another function. Surely, rewriting everything could be better but I've not the time nor the competence to do so. But that's not the point of the question. Does a more efficient way exist to create such big variables by appending

Comment: Have you checked the max size of the SQL your MySQL database will process as you may also have to configure this as well.

Comment: I have, I've no problem on the sql side. I receive a memory error specifically for this line

Comment: _“It's prepare stuff to be inserted in a mysql database”_ - what, you are inserting a data string with 3080000 in one go …? _“Does a more efficient way exist to create such big variables by appending”_ – you have not even figured out yet whether it is actually the process of appending that causes your issue, or if simply the content of the variable in itself is growing beyond what your memory limit allows, so it is rather pointless to search for alternative ways to handle that single line of code already.

Comment: _"Surely, rewriting everything could be better but I've not the time nor the competence to do so. But that's not the point of the question."_ ...on the contrary, it's extremely relevant - if you can break it down into smaller chunks and send it for output, you can potentially avoid running out of memory because you've tried to create one enormous string in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question made me wonder what the differences are and ran some tests using an array of 77 char long strings.

*Results as follows*

**Concat**

```
Start Memory Usage: 2097152 KB
Post Array Build Memory Usage: 6291456 KB
Concat without Quotes Time: 28.893930912018
Post Concat without Quotes Memory Usage: 6291456 KB
```

**Concat with Quotes**

*Test kept runnning out of memory and failing even at low loop amounts*

**Implode**

```
Start Memory Usage: 2097152 KB
Post Array Build Memory Usage: 6291456 KB
Implode Time: 19.913722991943
Implode Memory Usage: 6291456 KB
```

**Testing methods**

```
set_time_limit(180);

function convert_memory_usage($size) {
    if($size < 1024){
        return $size . " B";
    }
    else if(1048576)
    {
        return ($size / 1024) . " KB";
    }else{
        return ($size / 1048576) . " MB";
    }
} 

function implode_array($arr){
    $str = implode("", $arr);
}

function concat_without_quotes($arr){
    $str = "";
    foreach($arr as $s){
        $str .= $s;
    }
}

function concat_with_quotes($arr){
    $str = "";
    foreach($arr as $s){
        $str = "{$str}{$s}";
    } 
}

echo "Start Memory Usage: " . convert_memory_usage(memory_get_usage(true)) . "<br/>";

$string = "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456";
$array = [];
for($x = 0; $x < 40000; $x++){
    array_push($array, $string);
}

echo "Post Array Build Memory Usage: " . convert_memory_usage(memory_get_usage(true)) . "<br/>";

$start = microtime(true);

for($x = 0; $x < 10000; $x++){
    // Change method to loop here
    implode_array($array);
}

// And Uncomment as required

//echo "Implode Time: " . (microtime(true) - $start) . "</br>";
//echo "Implode Memory Usage: " . convert_memory_usage(memory_get_usage(true)) . "<br/>";

//echo "Concat with Quotes Time: " . (microtime(true) - $start) . "</br>";
//echo "Concat with Quotes Memory Usage: " . convert_memory_usage(memory_get_usage(true)) . "<br/>";

//echo "Concat without Quotes Time: " . (microtime(true) - $start) . "</br>";
//echo "Concat without Quotes Memory Usage: " . convert_memory_usage(memory_get_usage(true)) . "<br/>";
```

**Summary**
After these test you can see that `implode` appears to be the best method for joining lots of `strings`.

**Usage** `$long_string = implode("", $array_of_strings)`

*Using PHP Version 7.3.4*

Answer (score 0):

Well as mentioned in this comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php#60035, it is more efficient to concatenate strings by placing them inside double quotes. So a more efficient way of concatenating would be:

```
$values_string = "{$values_string}{$values},";
```

Comment: speed efficient or memory efficient? In the link, I see speed efficiency, not memory. I'm looking for memory efficiency.

Comment: Well Php has only two operators for working with strings. "." and ".=". You are using both operators in one statement. This may not be memory efficient. You can try to separate your code into two statements. The first one is `$values.=","`. The second one would be `$values_string.=$values`. If this does not work, then you can try to append the $values variable to an array as suggested in comment by @treyBake

Comment: Thanks Nadir, that looks like a good idea, I'm trying it. However, as the script does run ok sometimes and doesn't some other times (depending on server load I guess). I'll only be able to confirm if that fixed the issue or not in some time